# Get latest record when grouped by two columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that tracks version history.I want to get only the latest version along with the date for each id in the table.
The below will give me the latest date for each id,version combination.How can I select only the top record? I can store this in a temp table and then use join to get only the top record for each id,version combination.Is there a better way to accomplish this in a single step?

Sample data

```
id  version     timestamp
123 1.5         2015-03-28 08:21:04.563
123 1.0         2015-03-21 12:58:24.730
234 1.5         2016-10-15 23:08:09.550
345 1.5         2016-05-10 15:18:09.707
345 1.5         2016-09-02 21:30:00.657
```

Expected output

```
id  version     timestamp
123 1.5         2015-03-28 08:21:04.563
234 1.5         2016-10-15 23:08:09.550
345 1.5         2016-09-02 21:30:00.657
```

Query

```
select  id,version,max(dt_create)
from version_history (nolock) 
group by id,version
order by id
```

I have tried this but I get the same result as above

```
select * from 
( 
    select  id,version,dt_create,row_number() over (partition by id,version order by dt_create desc) as a
    from version_history (nolock) 
) b
where a=1
order by id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query I have works after I remove version from the partition clause

```
select * from 
( 
    select  id,version,dt_create,row_number() over (partition by id order by dt_create desc) as a
    from version_history (nolock) 
) b
where a=1
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WITH TIES clause

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] int,[version] varchar(50),[timestamp] datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (123,1.5,'2015-03-28 08:21:04.563')
,(123,1.0,'2015-03-21 12:58:24.730')
,(234,1.5,'2016-10-15 23:08:09.550')
,(345,1.5,'2016-05-10 15:18:09.707')
,(345,1.5,'2016-09-02 21:30:00.657')

Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  @YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order By timestamp Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
id  version timestamp
123 1.5     2015-03-28 08:21:04.563
234 1.5     2016-10-15 23:08:09.550
345 1.5     2016-09-02 21:30:00.657
```

Comment: Thanks.My table has 210 million records and this is taking 40+ mins.Using join I get back the results in 8 mins.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Happy you got a resolution.  Can't imagine why you were getting 40+ minutes  unless you were loading your data into the table variable.

Answer (score 1):

I see you were able to achieve this by partitioning, however I'd like to show you another approach.  You can compare performance for yourself and see what's fastest - (I'm assuming partitioning is better).

First, we know that there could be multiple dates for even the latest version, so you really don't want the max version for each id, rather you want the max date!

First, the setup:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, [Version] DECIMAL(18, 2), [TimeStamp] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
(123, 1.5, '2015-03-28 08:21:04.563'),
(123, 1.5, '2015-03-21 12:58:24.730'),
(234, 1.5, '2016-10-15 23:08:09.550'),
(345, 1.5, '2016-05-10 15:18:09.707'),
(345, 1.5, '2016-09-02 21:30:00.657')
```

Now, to get each ID with the max date:

```
SELECT ID, 
       MAX([TimeStamp]) AS MaxTimeStamp
FROM @table
GROUP BY ID
```

This gives us what we want:

```
ID          MaxTimeStamp
----------- -----------------------
123         2015-03-28 08:21:04.563
234         2016-10-15 23:08:09.550
345         2016-09-02 21:30:00.657

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Now we just need to include the version.  That should be easy, because we can do a self-join on ID and Date:

```
SELECT T.ID, 
       MAX(T.[TimeStamp]) AS [MaxTimeStamp], 
       T2.[Version] AS [MaxVersion]
FROM @table T
JOIN @table T2
    ON T.ID = T2.ID
    AND T.[TimeStamp] = T2.[TimeStamp]
GROUP BY T.ID, T2.[Version]
```

And this gives us the following results:

```
ID          MaxTimeStamp            MaxVersion
----------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
123         2015-03-28 08:21:04.563 1.50
234         2016-10-15 23:08:09.550 1.50
345         2016-09-02 21:30:00.657 1.50

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Note that we are joining our original query to the same table - by ID and Date, like discussed.  However, we are now selecting an additional column, Version, so it needs to be included in the `GROUP BY`

Alternatively, you can achieve the same results by using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  T.ID, 
        MAX(T.[TimeStamp]) AS MaxTimeStamp, 
        T2.[Version]
FROM @table T
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT Version 
        FROM @table T2
        WHERE T2.ID = T.ID  
        AND T2.[TimeStamp] = T.[TimeStamp]
    ) T2
GROUP BY T.ID, T2.[Version]
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers do not really select the latest on 2 columns. Just 1 column maxed timestamp.

If a previous version can have a later build date (eg a security bugfix) as a higher version then the setup could be like this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, [Version] DECIMAL(18, 2), [TimeStamp] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
 (123,1.5,'2015-03-28 08:21:04.563')
,(123,1.0,'2015-03-21 12:58:24.730')
,(123,1.0,'2016-03-21 12:58:24.730') --new
,(234,1.5,'2016-10-15 23:08:09.550')
,(345,1.5,'2016-05-10 15:18:09.707')
,(345,1.5,'2016-09-02 21:30:00.657')
```

The earlier answers would then result in 4 records now including the ID 123 with 1.0 version with 2016 date.
If thats not the intention then this would be the solution:

```
SELECT T.ID, 
       MAX(T.[TimeStamp]) AS [MaxTimeStamp], 
       T3.[Version] AS [MaxVersion]
FROM @table T
JOIN (
        SELECT T4.ID, 
           MAX(T4.[Version]) AS [MaxVersion]
        FROM @table T4
        GROUP BY T4.ID
    ) as T2 ON T.id = T2.id
JOIN @table T3
    ON T.ID = T3.ID
    --AND T2.ID = T3.ID --works fine somehow with or without thise line
    AND T.[TimeStamp] = T3.[TimeStamp]
    AND T3.[Version] = T2.[MaxVersion]
GROUP BY T.ID, T3.[Version]
```

I needed an extra join for this, but I'm wondering whether it could be without an extra join.